# Doing increments with one repeat function?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to run a function so that every time I type in just ***func v_new*** I echo out **v_1** and then **v_2** and so on. So basically incrementing the number each time.

my script is as follows:

```
counter=1;
counter=$((counter++))

function func {

Arg=$1

a=$(echo "$Arg" | cut -d '_' -f 2)  #This separates the word **new** from the variable

b=$(echo "$Arg" | cut -d '_' -f 1)  #This separates the letter **v** from the variable

c=$b"_"$counter  #Gives me the v_1

echo $c
}


If [[ $1 == "v_new" ]]
then
func
else
echo "Incorrect Argument"
fi
```

So when I run the function ***func v_new*** the first time it echoes v_1. However when I continue to run it, it just repeats v_1 each time without incrementing the name. Is there a mistake in the counter? Not sure where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If you're running `func v_new`, perhaps you should use `$1` in `func` so that its argument is actually used.

Comment: Edited. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the function changes the value of `i` or `counter`, so the result doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

You are only incrementing `counter` once, before `func` is defined. The line

```
counter=$((counter++))
```

doesn't say "increment `counter` each time it is expanded"; it just assigns the old value of `counter` back to the name `counter` before incrementing it. The assignment overwrites the increment, making the whole thing effectively a no-op.

You need to increment `counter` inside the function, so that it happens with every call.

```
func () {
    printf 'v_%d\n' "$((counter++))"
}
```

(There's no point hard-coding a value of `i`, only to break it into two pieces.)